# jQuery - Quantity increment math

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I get the value of each `.count` to change dynamically with the value entered into the `.qty` input for each `.item`?

```js
$(function() {
  $('.qtyplus').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    fieldName = $(this).attr('field');
    var currentVal = parseInt($('input[name=' + fieldName + ']').val());
    if (!isNaN(currentVal)) {
      $('input[name=' + fieldName + ']').val(currentVal + 1);
    } else {
      $('input[name=' + fieldName + ']').val(0);
    }
  });
  $(".qtyminus").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    fieldName = $(this).attr('field');
    var currentVal = parseInt($('input[name=' + fieldName + ']').val());
    if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal > 0) {
      $('input[name=' + fieldName + ']').val(currentVal - 1);
    } else {
      $('input[name=' + fieldName + ']').val(0);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">
  <div class="count">100</div>
  <div id='myform' method='POST' action='#'>
    <label for="">qty </label><input type='button' value='-' class='qtyminus' field='quantity' />
    <input type='text' name='quantity' value='0' class='qty' />
    <input type='button' value='+' class='qtyplus' field='quantity' />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <div class="count">75</div>
  <div id='myform' method='POST' action='#'>
    <label for="">qty </label><input type='button' value='-' class='qtyminus' field='quantity' />
    <input type='text' name='quantity' value='0' class='qty' />
    <input type='button' value='+' class='qtyplus' field='quantity' />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: normally i think id="myform" cannot be duplicated in a html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.closest` to select parent element and then use `.find` selector to only select those elements which are inside that parent element.

Updated your code a little with selecting `parent = $(this).closest('.item');` and then find `input` elements inside that parent using `$parent.find('input[name=' + fieldName + ']')`.

Added function `updateCount()` and set `val` property of `.count` at beginning.

Added `$('input[name=quantity]').keyup` event.

Below is the complete code.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.count').each(function() {
    $(this).data('val', $(this).text());
  });

  $('input[name=quantity]').keyup(function() {   
      updateCount($(this).closest('.item').find('.count'), $(this));    
  });

  $('.qtyplus').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $parent = $(this).closest('.item');
    fieldName = $(this).attr('field');
    var currentVal = parseInt($parent.find('input[name=' + fieldName + ']').val());
    if (!isNaN(currentVal)) {
      $parent.find('input[name=' + fieldName + ']').val(currentVal + 1);
    } else {
      $parent.find('input[name=' + fieldName + ']').val(0);
    }
    updateCount($parent.find('.count'), $parent.find('input[name=' + fieldName + ']'));
  });
  $(".qtyminus").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $parent = $(this).closest('.item');
    fieldName = $(this).attr('field');
    var currentVal = parseInt($parent.find('input[name=' + fieldName + ']').val());
    if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal > 0) {
      $parent.find('input[name=' + fieldName + ']').val(currentVal - 1);
    } else {
      $parent.find('input[name=' + fieldName + ']').val(0);
    }
    updateCount($parent.find('.count'), $parent.find('input[name=' + fieldName + ']'));
  });
});

function updateCount($count, $input) {
  $count.text(parseInt($count.data('val')) - (parseInt($input.val()) || 0));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">
  <div class="count">100</div>
  <div id='myform' method='POST' action='#'>
    <label for="">qty </label>
    <input type='button' value='-' class='qtyminus' field='quantity' />
    <input type='text' name='quantity' value='0' class='qty' />
    <input type='button' value='+' class='qtyplus' field='quantity' />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <div class="count">75</div>
  <div id='myform' method='POST' action='#'>
    <label for="">qty </label>
    <input type='button' value='-' class='qtyminus' field='quantity' />
    <input type='text' name='quantity' value='0' class='qty' />
    <input type='button' value='+' class='qtyplus' field='quantity' />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Karan. How do I get the value from each `.count` to change mathematically depending on the input value entered in the quantity field?

Comment: @KyleUnderhill I have changed `$(this).closest('#myform')` to `$(this).closest('.item')` in my code. Now `$parent.find('.count')` in my code is doing same as you are asking.

Comment: Instead of taking the value of what is entered in the input, i need the initial value from `.count` (100) to be subtracted with the entered value. So the value from `.count` will change based on the value entered.

Comment: @KyleUnderhill check now.

Comment: You have to enter your value and then press + or - to lock in the value in your current code. Could it be done on keyup?

Answer (score 1):

```js
function qtyplus(id) {
  var selectedInput = $('#' + id + ' input[name=quantity]');
  var inputValue = $('#' + id + ' input[name=quantity]').val();
  if (!isNaN(inputValue)) {
    selectedInput.val(parseInt(inputValue) + 1);
  } else {
    selectedInput.val(0);
  }
  var count = $('#' + id + ' .count');
  count.html(parseInt(count.html()) - 1);
}

function qtyminus(id) {
  var selectedInput = $('#' + id + ' input[name=quantity]');
  var inputValue = $('#' + id + ' input[name=quantity]').val();
  if (!isNaN(inputValue)) {
    selectedInput.val(parseInt(inputValue) - 1);
  } else {
    selectedInput.val(0);
  }
  var count = $('#' + id + ' .count');
  count.html(parseInt(count.html()) - 1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="item1" class="item">
  <div class="count">100</div>
  <div id='myform' method='POST' action='#'>
    <label for="">qty </label><input type='button' value='-' class='qtyminus' onClick="qtyminus('item1')" />
    <input type='text' name='quantity' value='0' class='qty' />
    <input type='button' value='+' class='qtyplus' onClick="qtyplus('item1')" />
  </div>
</div>
<div id="item2" class="item">
  <div class="count">75</div>
  <div id='myform' method='POST' action='#'>
    <label for="">qty </label><input type='button' value='-' class='qtyminus' onClick="qtyminus('item2')" />
    <input type='text' name='quantity' value='0' class='qty' />
    <input type='button' value='+' class='qtyplus' onClick="qtyplus('item2')" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This answer doesn't deduct from the original quantity or make each input work separately

Comment: Dear friend I changed my post please check it.

Comment: This is better, but I need the input to subtract from the initial qty. so the first "+" on the quantity input would put the first qty to 99, and so on

Comment: I changed it again. Please check it.

Comment: Yes like this. Except I just noticed that when you enter a value instead of incrementally by clicking the `input button`, the math doesn't compute